# Group header selection in dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, custom-server-controls

How to select an Group header in dropdownlist in asp.net

Comment: Try this post http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2006/12/27/dropdownlist-with-optgroup.aspx

Comment: this won't allow to select the header but yes allowing me to select the subsection under header...problem is i want to select the header as well